# only javascript: disable radio buttons in rows and columns

Tags: javascript, html

I found a [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113929/javascript-disable-a-single-radio-button) in here to disable radio buttons.

I want to add another set of radio buttons (Radio3) and have added the process functions so if I click a radio button of the first column (Radio1) the corresponding buttons Radio2 and Radio3 are disabled.

This also works fine: when clicking any other button the other buttons in that row are disabled. However, if Radio1 in the first line is clicked (Radio2 and Radio3 in the first line are now disabled) and then Radio 2 is clicked in the second row, the first row buttons are enabled again (except for Radio2_1).

How can I manage to keep them disabled so it is not possible to have two checked radio buttons in one row?

I must use a kind of if condition when clearing the previously disabled buttons so it leaves out those buttons that are in a row with one still checked button - but I have no idea how to do this...

```js
function process(rb) {

  //left column
  for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName("Radio2").length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByName("Radio2")[i].disabled = '';
  }
  document.getElementById(rb.id.replace('Radio1', 'Radio2')).disabled = 'disabled';


  for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName("Radio3").length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByName("Radio3")[i].disabled = '';
  }
  document.getElementById(rb.id.replace('Radio1', 'Radio3')).disabled = 'disabled';
}
//middle column
function process2(rb) {

  //clearing previos disabled
  for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName("Radio1").length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByName("Radio1")[i].disabled = '';
  }
  document.getElementById(rb.id.replace('Radio2', 'Radio1')).disabled = 'disabled';

  for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName("Radio3").length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByName("Radio3")[i].disabled = '';
  }
  document.getElementById(rb.id.replace('Radio2', 'Radio3')).disabled = 'disabled';
}

//right column
function process3(rb) {

  //clearing previos disabled
  for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName("Radio1").length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByName("Radio1")[i].disabled = '';
  }
  document.getElementById(rb.id.replace('Radio3', 'Radio1')).disabled = 'disabled';

  for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName("Radio2").length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByName("Radio2")[i].disabled = '';
  }
  document.getElementById(rb.id.replace('Radio3', 'Radio2')).disabled = 'disabled';
}

<table style="width: 50%;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="Radio1_1" type="radio" name="Radio1" onchange="process(this)" /><br />
      <input id="Radio1_2" type="radio" name="Radio1" onchange="process(this)" /><br />
      <input id="Radio1_3" type="radio" name="Radio1" onchange="process(this)" /><br />
      <input id="Radio1_4" type="radio" name="Radio1" onchange="process(this)" /><br />
      <input id="Radio1_5" type="radio" name="Radio1" onchange="process(this)" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="Radio2_1" type="radio" name="Radio2" onchange="process2(this)" /><br />
      <input id="Radio2_2" type="radio" name="Radio2" onchange="process2(this)" /><br />
      <input id="Radio2_3" type="radio" name="Radio2" onchange="process2(this)" /><br />
      <input id="Radio2_4" type="radio" name="Radio2" onchange="process2(this)" /><br />
      <input id="Radio2_5" type="radio" name="Radio2" onchange="process2(this)" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="Radio3_1" type="radio" name="Radio3" onchange="process3(this)" /><br />
      <input id="Radio3_2" type="radio" name="Radio3" onchange="process3(this)" /><br />
      <input id="Radio3_3" type="radio" name="Radio3" onchange="process3(this)" /><br />
      <input id="Radio3_4" type="radio" name="Radio3" onchange="process3(this)" /><br />
      <input id="Radio3_5" type="radio" name="Radio3" onchange="process3(this)" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here the HTML Code with the table format:

```
document.getElementById("tb").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  const rads = [...tgt.closest("tr").querySelectorAll("[type=radio]")];
  const choiceIndicii = rads.map(rad => rad.checked ? rad.id.split("_")[1] : ""); // already taken
  rads.forEach(rad =>  rad.disabled = choiceIndicii.includes(rad.id.split("_")[1]));
})
<table>
    <tbody id='tb'>
        <tr>
            <td><input id='Radio1_1' type='radio' name='Radio1' value='21'/></td>
            <td><input id='Radio2_1' type='radio' name='Radio2' value='21'/></td>
            <td><input id='Radio3_1' type='radio' name='Radio3' value='21'/></td>
            <td> more Info </td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td><input id='Radio1_2' type='radio' name='Radio1' value='22'/></td>
            <td><input id='Radio2_2' type='radio' name='Radio2' value='22'/></td>
            <td><input id='Radio3_2' type='radio' name='Radio3' value='22'/></td>
            <td> more Info </td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td><input id='Radio1_3' type='radio' name='Radio1' value='23'/></td>
            <td><input id='Radio2_3' type='radio' name='Radio2' value='23'/></td>
            <td><input id='Radio3_3' type='radio' name='Radio3' value='23'/></td>
            <td> more Info </td>
        </tr>       
        <tr>
            <td><input id='Radio1_4' type='radio' name='Radio1' value='25'/></td>
            <td><input id='Radio2_4' type='radio' name='Radio2' value='25'/></td>
            <td><input id='Radio3_4' type='radio' name='Radio3' value='25'/></td>
            <td> more Info </td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td><input id='Radio1_5' type='radio' name='Radio1' value='33'/></td>
            <td><input id='Radio2_5' type='radio' name='Radio2' value='33'/></td>
            <td><input id='Radio3_5' type='radio' name='Radio3' value='33'/></td>
            <td> more Info </td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td><input id='Radio1_6' type='radio' name='Radio1' value='54'/></td>
            <td><input id='Radio2_6' type='radio' name='Radio2' value='54'/></td>
            <td><input id='Radio3_6' type='radio' name='Radio3' value='54'/></td>
            <td> more Info </td>
        </tr>       
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not have selects and test the choice is not already taken?

```js
document.getElementById("tb").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  const sels = [...tgt.closest("tr").querySelectorAll("select")];
  const choiceIndicii = sels.map(sel => sel.value === "" ? -1 : sel.value.split("_")[1]); // already taken
  sels.forEach(sel => [...sel.querySelectorAll("option")]
    .forEach(opt => opt.disabled = choiceIndicii.includes(opt.value.split("_")[1]))
  );  
})
```

```html
<table style="width: 50%;">
  <tbody id="tb">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select id="select_1" class="choice">
          <option value="">First choice</option>
          <option value="Choice1_1">Choice 1</option>
          <option value="Choice1_2">Choice 2</option>
          <option value="Choice1_3">Choice 3</option>
          <option value="Choice1_4">Choice 4</option>
          <option value="Choice1_5">Choice 5</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select id="select_2" class="choice">
          <option value="">Second choice</option>
          <option value="Choice2_1">Choice 1</option>
          <option value="Choice2_2">Choice 2</option>
          <option value="Choice2_3">Choice 3</option>
          <option value="Choice2_4">Choice 4</option>
          <option value="Choice2_5">Choice 5</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select id="select_3" class="choice">
          <option value="">Third choice</option>
          <option value="Choice3_1">Choice 1</option>
          <option value="Choice3_2">Choice 2</option>
          <option value="Choice3_3">Choice 3</option>
          <option value="Choice3_4">Choice 4</option>
          <option value="Choice3_5">Choice 5</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Trying the same with radios

```js
document.getElementById("tb").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  const rads = [...tgt.closest("tr").querySelectorAll("[type=radio]")];
  const choiceIndicii = rads.map(rad => rad.checked ? rad.id.split("_")[1] : ""); // already taken
  rads.forEach(rad =>  rad.disabled = choiceIndicii.includes(rad.id.split("_")[1]));
})
```

```html
<table style="width: 50%;">
  <tbody id="tb">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="Radio1_1" type="radio" name="Radio1" /><br />
        <input id="Radio1_2" type="radio" name="Radio1" /><br />
        <input id="Radio1_3" type="radio" name="Radio1" /><br />
        <input id="Radio1_4" type="radio" name="Radio1" /><br />
        <input id="Radio1_5" type="radio" name="Radio1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="Radio2_1" type="radio" name="Radio2" /><br />
        <input id="Radio2_2" type="radio" name="Radio2" /><br />
        <input id="Radio2_3" type="radio" name="Radio2" /><br />
        <input id="Radio2_4" type="radio" name="Radio2" /><br />
        <input id="Radio2_5" type="radio" name="Radio2" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="Radio3_1" type="radio" name="Radio3" /><br />
        <input id="Radio3_2" type="radio" name="Radio3" /><br />
        <input id="Radio3_3" type="radio" name="Radio3" /><br />
        <input id="Radio3_4" type="radio" name="Radio3" /><br />
        <input id="Radio3_5" type="radio" name="Radio3" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The idea is that the user can make three choices (1st wish, 2nd wish, 3rd wish - these are the columns). The different things to choose from is given in the rows (in my examples five things to choose from). It must not be possible to have more than one wish in one row, so only 1st, 2nd OR 3rd wish in one row. But it should be possible to change the vote. Example: Radio1_1, Radio2_2, Radio3_3 are checked. Now change from Radio1_1 to Radio1_4 should be possible and Radio1_1, Radio2_1, Radio 3_1 should be enabled again. In total there can only be three checked radio buttons.

Comment: The first code from you is better for me. But if I change from Radio1_1 to Radio 1_2 the radios in the first line should be enabled again

Comment: Please see my update. It takes less space and works as you want

Comment: I have a bigger table behind this set of choices with lots of information in each row. I cannot put that into select fields. So unfortunately I have to stick with the radio buttons. But can't it work the same with radio buttons (testing which choice is already taken)?

Comment: @ayanu99 Trying with radios. See if that does what you want. Radios are not supposed to be deselected. What do you want to do with that?

Comment: I want users to choose courses for a holiday camp. They have three wishes and can give them their preferred order. The new script works fine although I'll try to keep the current choices buttons active so it looks better. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is the same also possible within a table? I have added the radio button list sortet a bit diferrently but essentialy the same as before in the table form below my old code but I haven't managed to change your script so it works there.

Comment: Very likely. I am not near a computer for a while- show your table in an update to your question